# Should we use `token` or `spl-token` for tags related to tokens on Solana?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Tokens are usually what people know on blockchains, but spl-token is the specific program on Solana. Should we use `token` or `spl-token` for questions related to tokens on Solana?

Answer (score 3):

This is a great question. I could convince myself of either but I think I'd prefer to use the actual name of the program.

I feel like it would be more clear when/if people have questions about `spl-token-2022` or another token program that doesn't belong to the solana program library.

Comment: Doesn't `spl-token-2022` belong to the solana program library? I know it's a new standard, but I'd still consider token 2022 tokens still SPL tokens.